# javascript replace text in textarea not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, append, textarea

My app is grabbing the user's input in the textarea div, calling an API, and then returning values. The returned values are pushed into the badWords array and then compared to the user's input. If there is a match a word is considered to be spelled wrong or a "badword."

When a word is a "badword" I am coloring it red.

My issue is that my JS is working in the Test Div. When I change the ID from test div to the textarea div in:

```
$('#test').append(str);
```

and in:

```
var p = document.getElementById('test');
```

to:

```
"#user-input"
```

and:

```
"user-input"
```

nothing shows up on the screen nor in the textarea.

I have tried fixing this for a few days and am driving myself up a wall. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<!-- Test Div -->
<!-- Here is where the input is going -->
<div id="test"></div>

<!-- Textarea Div -->
<!-- I want user input to go here -->
<textarea id="user-input" class="input-class" type="text" placeholder="Enter your bad grammar"></textarea>
```

JS/JQ:

```
var str = $("#user-input").val().trim();
$('#test').append(str);

// Stores the bad words or error words
var badWords = [];

// Stores the better words to be used for improvement
var betterWords = [];

// Looping through the results returned by API
for (var i = 0; i < response.errors.length; i++) {

badWords.push(response.errors[i].bad)
betterWords.push(response.errors[i].better)
}

var p = document.getElementById('test');
            var newInput = p.innerHTML
            console.log(newInput);

            badWords.forEach(function (bWord) {
                console.log('bad word ', bWord);
                newInput = newInput.replace(bWord, `<span class="color badword">${bWord}<span class="tooltiptext">try :'${betterWords}</span></span>`)
            });

            p.innerHTML = newInput

        })
```

Comment: Can you provide fiddle or code snipset?

Comment: you cannot add spans into a textarea. It is invalid HTML

Comment: I quickly made a codepen. Now nothing is working: https://jsfiddle.net/dkhkvcpf/10/

Answer (score 2):

Try with `val` instead of append or replace

I think:

`p.val(newInput)`

Alternatives:

Use a div with `contenteditable` instead of the textarea

Comment: I was going to suggest this, but you cannot add span text colors inside a textarea

Comment: I think this should append the HTML tags, this might be the desired output

Comment: After I get the text to color, and go into the same field that it was entered in, I want to be able to hover over that red word, see list of suggested replacements, thus the span in the last function.

Comment: I think that you could go on codepen.io and try to write some code that can help us help you. basically, a demo of your problem with as little code as possible, trying to focus on your exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change Textarea with Input because I think we can't do it with Textarea

Comment: I was actually having the same issue with input but I will try this too. I moved away from input because I had read somewhere on SO that if you want to dynamically have the field adjust, it is better to use the textarea with jquery